# Not getting checkbox control value of a panel

Tags: c#, html

I have a panel

```
<tr id="trs" runat="server" style="width:100%;">
<td>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%">   
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" /> <input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" /></div>                             
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" /> <input id="Text2" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" /> <input id="Text3" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
            <div id="row4" style="display:none;" ><input type="checkbox" id="chk4" /> <input id="Text4" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
            <div id="row5" style="display:none;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk5" /> <input id="Text5" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
            <div id="row6" style="display:none;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk6" /> <input id="Text6" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
            <div id="row7" style="display:none;"><input type="checkbox" id="chk7" /> <input id="Text7" type="text" runat="server" /></div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add more.." OnClientClick="AddMoreOptions();" />
    </asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please advice how can I get checkbox and textbox values? The code I have written so far:

```
    for (int i=1; i<8; i++)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText textbox = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)Panel1.FindControl("Text" + i); // This works and gives me textbox value.
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox checkbox = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)Panel1.FindControl("chk" + i);

        if (textbox.Value != "") 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to get both the values?

Comment: textbox are already `runat="server"`, make checkbox too, you don't need to find server side control using `HtmlControls` it can directly access like `Text1.text`

Answer (score 0):

You have made your controls `runat="server"`, so you can get the value directly by their `Id`. something like this `var firstTextValue = Text1.Text` and for checkboxes you could do something like this `bool isChecked = chk1.Checked`.